# jQuery how to stop Vimeo video when click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, vimeo

here is the simple code: http://jsfiddle.net/YAFuW/1/

basicly i tried to use like this:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/40977539?api=1" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>

<a href="#">STOP</a>

$('a').click(function() {
   alert('stoped');
   froogaloop.api('unload');
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know a "good" or "right" way to accomplish this cross-browser.
Youtube's JavaScript API fails, too.

But this method is reliable and does work.
Basically, it kills the `<iframe>` and rebuilds it.

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  alert('stoped');
  vimeoWrap = $('#vimeoWrap');
  vimeoWrap.html(vimeoWrap.html());
});
```

[View at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JxBE4/)

Comment: it does not work again. it's work one time only. again page refresh after only it work. i need again and again i click play and stop. it run automatically with out page reload.

Comment: What browser are you in? It works repeatedly in Chrome.

Answer (score 15):

if you need only play or pause video use like this:

```
var iframe = $('#vimeo-player')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);

$('#stop').click(function() {
    alert('stoped');
    player.api('pause');
});


$('#play').click(function(){
    alert('play');
    player.api('play');
})
```

and markup:

```
<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>

<iframe id="vimeo-player" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/40977539?api=1" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
<a id="stop" href="#">STOP</a>
<a id="play" href="#">PLAY</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zimm/8CV2S/14/

Comment: Though very much old post but served my purpose nicely. Thanks.

Comment: Vimeo seems to have recently stopped supporting this. Is there a new API that can be used?

Comment: Finally the answer I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Great answer, it saved my day! I have a question though, Is https://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js -> (Your connection is not private)  the official CDN for vimeo? I checked their [GitHub](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js), and it says: player.vimeo.com/api/player.js, [This Image](http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/117/311/117311910_1280.jpg) & [This Image](https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/483508229_295x166.jpg) made me paranoid, plus they don't have SSL?! The code looks fine I guess...Yet I have seen people scanning the script [Ref](https://www.google.com/search?q=f9624433f960dcd3ebdb2eb2b948e9cf)!

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to work with [Vimeo API](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js):

Example:

```
<script>
    var iframe = $('.vimeo-iframe').get(0);
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
    player.pause();
    //player.play();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed get the id of the vimeo video:

```
var iframe = $('#vimeo-player')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);
player.api('unload');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/joan_r/dutzh512/

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<style>
#play,#pause,#stop{
    width:60px;
    margin:5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid;
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="vimeo-player" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="play">[PLAY]</div>
<div id="pause">[PAUSE]</div>
<div id="stop">[STOP]</div>
<script>
    $('#play').click(function() {
        var iframe = $('#vimeo-player')[0];
        var player = $f(iframe);
        player.api('play');
    });
    $('#pause').click(function() {
        var iframe = $('#vimeo-player')[0];
        var player = $f(iframe);
        player.api('pause');
    });
    $('#stop').click(function() {
        var iframe = $('#vimeo-player')[0];
        var player = $f(iframe);
        player.api('unload');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vimeo's updated API code then you can do it like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/deshg/8CV2S/. You can see the stop button now gives you the alert and then the video is unloaded.

Cheers!