# Stopping any vimeo video on the page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

sorry about my inexperience. I was given a certain html code:

```
    <div class="embedded-video" style="display: block;">
        <span class="fa fa-times-circle video-closer">Close</span>
        <p></p>
        <div>
            <iframe allowfullscreen class="roots-video" frameborder="0" height="360" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/155722997?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" style="display: block;" width="640"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div>
            <iframe allowfullscreen class="roots-video" frameborder="0" height="360" id="spvideo" name="spvideo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/155722997?title=0&amp;autopause=1&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" style="display: block;" width="640"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need a "close" button that stops the videos, whichever one is playing at the moment, or all that are playing, since you will only be able to play one a time.

I used a solution copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12932722/3808307

adding

```
<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
var iframe = $('.roots-video')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);

$('.video-closer').click(function() {
    alert('stoped');
    player.api('pause');
});
```

But it obviously only works for the first video. How do I get the close to work for all the elements of the array? I don't care about performance here, I just want the close to stop all the videos that are playing if I cannot identify which one is playing

Answer (score 2):

I don't have idea how it works but just a guess according to your exists code

```
$('.video-closer').click(function() {
    $('.roots-video').each(function(){
       var ele = $f(this);
       ele.api('pause');
    });
});
```